# Property file always fails to load immediately when I create a new android application project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

For a while, every time I try to run an Android application project, get an error message saying *there are errors in your project*. Every time that happens I have get an **x** in the project folder of every Android application project I create (None of the project folder contents have x's on it though).

To make sure that the error is not my fault, I tried creating a sample Android project to see what happens and I still get that error. So I viewed the error log and every time I create a new Android project I always get an error saying *property file fails to load*. I tried rebuilding the file, I tried cleaning it, and I tried checking the property file and nothing works.

Can you give suggestions on what I can do about it? If there is any more information you need please let me know and I'll provide it for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i faced this problem before and i think you need to re- install the eclipse and refer android sdk  on new installation

Comment: Can I still keep my project workplace? Also what do you mean by refer android sdk on new installation?

Comment: after you re install the eclipse again you will need to  link the ADT and android sdk (actually it on your hard ) and when eclipse ask you for the work space direct it on old work space you have already

Comment: Tried it did not work. Do you have other suggestions? Other wise I may try a different sdk bundle.